# Cost curve analysis: how to standardize projects over a 96 month timeline?

Tags: linear-regression, curve

I'm working on creating a standard cost curve for various projects, by type and sub-type.  I have expense data for all 216 projects who have a start and end time between 96 months.  I've been trying to standardize the projects so that I can compare apples to apples the expense curves of each so that I can plot the average cost curve for the type and subtype of project category. I am not a data scientist so I have reached the end of my knowledge and would appreciate any guidance as to how to complete this task.

I've attempted plotting on line and column charts in Excel but I cannot seem to figure out the best linear trend line that encapsulates all data since they range in start periods.